# Can I fit a C# Guid inside a Dynamo Numeric Type?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I want to do this because I'm assuming guids are rare enough that collisions won't be a problem; and the table I'm using already has N.  DynamoDB documentation claims that you can store up to 38 bits of precision in an N field.  But it seems that the BigInteger version of guids runs up to 2**127-1, which has 39 digits of precision.  How can I do this?

A backup plan would be to convert the N field to string, but I would not like to modify the schema.

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't work.  The integer generated by the following code is the largest guid.  If you try to insert it you will get the exception:

```
AmazonDynamoDbException occurred for XXX. RequestId: YYY with message: Attempting to store more than 38 significant digits in a Number
```

Here is how to construct the maximum number:

```
var largest = GuidToBigInteger (new Guid("ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff7f"));
//{ 170141183460469231731687303715884105727} == 2**127 - 1
```

Here are the helper functions to convert Guids into BigIntegers, and back.

```
public BigInteger GetPowerOfTwo(int pow)
{
    BigInteger n = 1;
    while (pow > 0)
    {
        n = n * 2;
        pow--;
    }
    return n;
}

private byte[] RightPadWithByte(byte[] input, byte pad)
{
    var newInput = new byte[16];
    for (var ii = 0; ii < 16; ii++)
    {
        if (ii < input.Length)
        {
            newInput[ii] = input[ii];
        }
        else
        {
            newInput[ii] = pad;
        }
    }
    return newInput;
}

public Guid MakeGuidFromBigInteger(BigInteger n)
{
    var bytes = n.ToByteArray();
    byte pad;
    if (n < 1)
    {
        pad = 0xff;
    }
    else
    {
        pad = 0x00;
    }
    var paddedBytes = RightPadWithByte(bytes, pad);
    var guid = new Guid(paddedBytes);
    return guid;
}

public BigInteger GuidToBigInteger(Guid guid)
{
    byte[] guidAsBytes = guid.ToByteArray();
    BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(guidAsBytes);
    return bigInteger;
}
```